# RegEx Match Group Help (VB)

Tags: regex

I'm stuck trying to match the following from a .txt file.

Sample of data:

```
A1  "1.1","1.2"
[JOB 1]
H1  "[_Name]LE 
[_Addr1]123Rd 
[_Addr2] 
[CityStZip]4863
[Zip]48911 
[Phone](248-
[FullName]C, M
"
D1  "  C"
```

Each data group will start with [JOB #] \n H1 \t "{Data I'm Attempting to Parse}"

I'm trying to match it such that [_Name], [_Addr1], etc are the  and whatever is after the key is the value. Each line begins with a \n in this file format.

Code will match the first line, but no further; where did i go wrong?

```
(?<=H1\t")((?<key>\[.*])(?<value>.*))
```

Comment: `.` matches all characters *other than* line terminators (`\n` or, for Windows, `\r\n`). Therefore, `(?<value>.*))` matches the remainder of the line only. Is that the problem? If so, there is a flag you can set to cause `.` to match all characters including line terminators. Alternatively, you can use `[\s\S]` (or `[\w\W]`, etc.), which matches all characters, in place of `.`. If you do that you still need a way to keep `(?<value>.*)` from matching the remainder of the string.

Comment: You can't match multiple `(?<key>\[.*])(?<value>.*)` values in the same search with a `*` - you actually need to match them all individually.  But you can do this: https://regex101.com/r/1hPmDj/1  (this one uses two spaces instead of a \t after the H1)

Comment: You can match multiple times: [`(?<=H1\s+"(?:\[[^[\]]+\].*\n)*)\[[^[\]]+\].*?(?=\s*\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/lOkMom/1).